# simple form not redirect to given action from an email

Tags: php, email

What i want to achieve:

I have a simple html form and I sent that form via phpmailer, and the email is successfully sent. but the problem is when I click on the submit button in the email, the form is not redirecting anywhere not showing any alert etc.

the form is:

```
<table align='center' width='630' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='4' style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <form action='http://www.example.com/users/mailing/mail_layout/post_buyer_form_mail.php' name="dataform" method='post'>
        <tr>
            <td  colspan="2" align='left'><label style='font-weight:bold;font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;'>Product you are looking to By :</label><br />
                <input style='font-size:11px;color:#666;padding:3px;' name='pb_title' size='120' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align='left' valign='top'><label style='font-weight:bold;font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;'>Describe your Buying Requirements in details :</label><br />
                <textarea name="pb_requirement" style='font-size:11px;color:#666;padding:3px;resize:none;' cols="86" rows="5"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

not able to understand where is the problem, this is first time that i send a complete form to an email and redirect it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting your form tags around the table tags, see if that helps.

```
<form...>
  <table>
  ...
  </table>
</form>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I think some email clients will not allow submitting forms from email. Your code should work OK from a webpage however.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works, actually i don't had idea about that :)